# Prettier VSCODE reformat on save has stopped working

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I can reformat the document by typing shift cmd p and type "Format document". This reformats. But when I save it does not (although it used to)

the format on save settings are below

```
"editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file"
```

editor default formatter is esben-prettier-vscode
javascript formatter is enable

Comment: Go to VS code settings. Search "Format on Save" . Make sure its enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change it to

```
"editor.formatOnSaveMode": "true"
```

or you set it language wise eg:

```
 "[html]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  },
```